# Реализация просмотра профиля пользователя MVC, PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Я изучаю MVC, не могу разобраться в следующей проблеме: 
Есть сайт, хочу сделать просмотр профиля пользователя. 
Хочется чтобы работало в таком виде: name.loc/users/admin 
Получается, что в данном случае users - контроллер, а admin - метод контроллера 
По умолчанию action = index. Как сделать, чтобы мы получали имя пользователя, подставляли его и выводили данные о пользователе?

```
class Controller_Users extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new Model_Users();
        $this->view = new View();
    }

    function action_index()
    {   
        $this->view->generate('users_view.php', 'template_view.php');
    }

}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, может я что-то не так понял?

Comment: а какой фреймверк изучаете? судя по логике нужнов контроллер добавить метод `function action_admin() { $this->view->generate('admin_view.php', 'template_view.php'); }` и соответственно представление `views/user/admin_view.php`

Comment: подумайте над тем чтобы поменять роутинг ибо он не логичный, например сделать контроллер `user` и в него методы: `~/user` - получает всех юзеров, `[GET]~/user/id` -получает опред пользователя.`[POST]~/user` - добавить пользователя. `[PUT]~/user/id` - изменить оперд пользователя. `[DELETE]~/user/id` - удалить оперд пользователя.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц это не фреймворк, нашел на хабре MVC и решил покопаться в нём. Чтобы понять как устроен MVC)
Просто не логично добавлять метод для каждого из пользователей, а вдруг их будет больше 1000, мы же не будем для каждого добавлять вручную )

Comment: вы меня не поняли. что значит для каждого из пользователей? и за какой именно метод идется? Метод будет один. ОН будет  принимать например id пользователя и в зависсимости от этого id выводить с модели результат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уточню что

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->model = new Model_Users();
    $this->view = new View();
}
```

Должен быть внутри `Controller` а не у `Controller_Users` и других производных.

---

**Вариант 1 (правильный):**

По поводу вашего вопроса, данную проблему решает `route`. Это один из неотъемлемых модулей при реализации `MVC`.

`Route` - это то, что принимает на вход `name.loc/users/admin` и понимает что нужно вызвать именно `Controller_user` а не другой любой контроллер, и в вашем случае запросить у него метод `admin`. Вот при настройке роутов, там можно указать так: при запросе `/users/` запрашивать `Controller_user` + его метод `viewInfo`, где `viewInfo` принимает параметр - ник логина который надо вывести. Приблизительно вот так выглядит это дело в контроллере:

```
class Controller_Users extends Controller
{
    function viewInfo($nickname)
    {   
        // тут выводим страничку для юзера с ником $nickname
    }
}
```

А в роуте это дело описывается по разному, все зависит от того, какой у вас фреймворк, либо если своя реализация, то такой функционал придется добавить. Приведу пару разных примеров, как у фреймов это выглядит:

В **CodeIgniter**: `$route['users/(:any)'] = 'controller_users/viewInfo/$1';`

В **Laravel**: `Route::get('users/{nickname}',function($nickname){...вызов Controller_Users@viewInfo/$nickname...})`

---

**Вариант 2 (костыльный):**

Если у вас при `name.loc/users/admin`, `users` - это контроллер, а `admin` - метод, при этом ваш роутер позволяет указать что при `users` контроллер `Controller_Users`, то можно заюзать магические методы. Самостоятельный пример:

```
class Controller_Users 
{
    public function __call($name, array $params)
    {
        if ($name == 'admin') {
            echo 'OK';
        }
    }

}
$controller = new Controller_Users();
$controller->admin();
```

Для статичного класса существует: `__callStatic`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробую первый вариант реализовать.
Пользовался статьей с Habr по реализации MVC: https://habr.com/ru/post/150267/
Решил его разобрать и понять как работает сам MVC

Comment: Что можете сказать насчет этой реализации MVC, которая на хабре?

Comment: @NeroKore ничего хорошего... Во-первых, статье 7ой год... Во-вторых, про безопасность и прочие плюхи речи даже не идет. Возьмите лучше тот-же `CodeIgniter` либо `Yii` для изучения, если вы разберетесь с одним из фреймов то увидите во сколько раз они превосходят то что на хабре. "Изучать MVC" по той статье, очень спорно, статья действительно показывает концепцию **но не более**, не показывает "боевую реализацию" даже для простых проектов.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, очень помогли. Какой бы порекомендовали для начинающего фреймворк? CodeIgnitier или Yii? Какой будет попроще в изучении и понимании?

Comment: @NeroKore проще будет `CI 3`, `Yii` - будет чуть сложнее, но ближе к реальным проектам. но для начала покрутите `CI 3`, понятная документация и сам фрейм очень простой, но поругать его не за что. P.S. **просто** на будущее: если вы хотите чтобы в будущем вам тут помогали, то не скупитесь на галочку и плюсик для тех ответов что были для вас полезны, так вы поощряете людей за уделенное, на вас, время.